# How to pass (and set) non-objects by indirection?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, indirection, multiple-indirection

NSError objects are frequently used like this (taken from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903103/why-does-nserror-need-double-indirection-pointer-to-a-pointer)):

```
- (id)doStuff:(id)withAnotherObjc error:(NSError **)error;
```

I want to achieve something similar with BOOL indirection:

```
- (id)doStuff:(id)withAnotherObjc andExtraBoolResult:(BOOL **)extraBool;
```

But I can't figure out how to get this working correctly.

For the given method specification involving NSError, the proper implementation would involve something like (again from [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903103/why-does-nserror-need-double-indirection-pointer-to-a-pointer)):

```
*error = [NSError errorWithDomain:...];
```

With similar logic, it seems like this should work with BOOL indirection:

```
*extraBool = &YES; // ERROR! Address expression must be an lvalue or a function designator
```

Why doesn't this work and what is the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that with objects, you're working with a pointer (e.g., `NSError*`), so using this method, you wind up with a pointer to a pointer (e.g., `NSError**`). When working with a `BOOL`, though, you should use a pointer to a BOOL: that is, only one level of indirection, not two. Therefore, you mean:

```
- (id)doStuff:(id)withAnotherObjc andExtraBoolResult:(BOOL *)extraBool;
```

and subsequently:

```
*extraBool = YES;
```

Comment: This was exactly my first pass. But then it wouldn't compile, so I tried to rationalize it with a poor understanding of pointers. I thought `*a = b` would actually change memory that `a` is pointing at to contain `b`, and so I thought this wouldn't work with `BOOL`s since I assumed every `YES` and `NO` is the same memory; upon second thought, this is bogus and `*a = b` clearly just updates `a` to point to the memory containing `b`. I honestly have no clue why it wouldn't compile before; it's working fine now, whoops.

Comment: Actually, that's incorrect. What `*a = b` does is dereference `a` and set the result to `b`, so `a` does not change (it remains a pointer to the same spot in memory); what happens is that same spot in memory is rewritten to contain `b`.

Comment: Do check for NULL. If it is NULL and that isn't allowed, throw an NSInvalidArgumentException.