# how to fix Clang alert in method using double indirection for NSError?

Tags: cocoa, clang, nserror

in a project using garbage collection:
**Clang** alerts 'Potential null dereference....' on line assigning *anError.

But this look right to me according to: [Why does NSError need double indirection? (pointer to a pointer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903103/why-does-nserror-need-double-indirection-pointer-to-a-pointer)

Can anyone see what i'm not seeing ?

```
- (NSData *)bookmarkDataForCurrentURL:(NSURL *)theURL error:(NSError **)anError
{
    NSArray *bkKeys = [CBPrepCommon bookmarkPropertyKeys];
    NSError *errorA = nil;
    NSData *bkmark = [theURL bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationPreferFileIDResolution includingResourceValuesForKeys:bkKeys relativeToURL:nil error:&errorA];

    if (![bkmark length] > 0) {
    if (errorA) {
        // error here
        *anError = [NSError errorWithDomain:[errorA domain] code:[errorA code] userInfo:[errorA userInfo]];
    }
    return nil;
}
return bkmark;
```

}

Comment: It looks OK to me too, assuming that your incoming parameters are good.  Does the message go away if you put `if (anError) {...}` around your assignment to `*anError`?

Comment: yes, but i don't understand why or how if (anError) {
    *anError = [NSError errorWithDomain:[errorA domain] code:[errorA code] userInfo:[errorA userInfo]];
   } would be called ?

Comment: It's telling you that you're not protected from the case of something calling `NSData *data = [anObject bookmarkDataForCurrentURL:theURL error:nil];`, which is true but not something a compiler has typically concerned itself with.

Comment: do i check at the top to see if anError isn't referenced -- not sure how to write that...if &anError == nil { return; }, because the caller is declaring NSError *errorX = nil, then plugging that into the method call as &errorX.

Comment: You could try `if (!anError) {return;}`.  I don't know if that will make the compiler happy or not...or you could leave the test as you have it in the above comment.

Comment: thanks phillip, for helping me think this through. i can't mark you comments as an answer, so no way to add to your rep except upvote your comment.

Comment: Something similar happened to me, but on iOS (no GC, no ARC). I had forgotten to initialize the NSError variable to nil before passing the reference. But your code seems to have that one covered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (errorA && anError) {
    // error here
    *anError = [NSError errorWithDomain:[errorA domain] code:[errorA code] userInfo:[errorA userInfo]];
}
```

EDIT: Even cleaner:

```
- (NSData *)bookmarkDataForCurrentURL:(NSURL *)theURL error:(NSError **)anError
{
    NSArray *bkKeys = [CBPrepCommon bookmarkPropertyKeys];
    NSData *bkmark = [theURL bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationPreferFileIDResolution includingResourceValuesForKeys:bkKeys relativeToURL:nil error:anError];

    if ([bkmark length] == 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    return bkmark;
}
```

Comment: Also, what are you using theURL for?  You're passing nil to bookmarkDataWithOptions:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeToURL:error.

Comment: i'm passing it in as a property of a NSManagedObject, during the managedObject's creation, so its okay for it to be nil, i think, so i can fail the NSManagedObject's creation in the caller's method, and examine the error. your second idea produces a warning for me 'incompatible pointer types sending NSError***] to 'NSError **'

Comment: Typo.  Changed &anError to just anError, that should fix the warning.